# Identifying the string in front of a given sequence of a word

Tags: python, regex

I have a text sentence as  'My Father is an American, and he is handsome' and 'My Mother is from North America and she is nice'.

I need to extract the word that is in front of the word `American` (In this case `an`) and `America` (In this case `North`) to be displayed to the console.

Note: the word `America` has a postfix `America + n` that makes it `American`, in the 2nd sentence.

My code so far:::

```
for line in words:
    for word in line.strip().split(' '):
         // HERE I SHOULD WRITE THE CODE TO IDENTIFY THE WORD BEFORE THE STRING 'AMERICA*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
x='My Father is an American, and he is handsome. My Mother is from North America and she is nice'

y = x.split()[1:]
for (i,j) in enumerate(y):
    if j.startswith('America'):
        print y[i-1]

an
North
```

Comment: What if the first word is `'America'`?

Comment: No, it should be 2 sentences. 'My Father is an American, and he is handsome.' is just one sentence.

Answer (score 4):

How about this?

```
import re

s = """
My Father is an American, and he is handsome
My Mother is from North America and she is nice
"""

print re.findall(r"(\w+)\sAmerica", s)
```

prints:

```
['an', 'North']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are to use regular expressions, your approach is incorrect. Just parse the whole sentence. A look-ahead assertion will give you the word before `America` or `American`:

```
re.findall(r'\w+(?=\s+American?)', line)
```

Demo:

```
>>> line = 'My Father is an American, and he is handsome'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+(?=\s+American?)', line)
['an']
>>> line = 'My Mother is from North America and she is nice'
>>> re.findall(r'\w+(?=\s+American?)', line)
['North']
```

This also works on a *whole* body of text:

```
>>> text = '''\
... My Father is an American, and he is handsome
... My Mother is from North America and she is nice
... '''
>>> re.findall(r'\w+(?=\s+American?)', text)
['an', 'North']
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
line = 'My Father is an American, and he is handsome'

words = line.split()
i = words.index("American,")
print words[i-1]
```

this will print `an`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the sentences are seperated but if they are in a list of sentences you could use.

```
import re
for line in sentences:
   sentence = line.strip().split(" ")
   for word in sentence:
       if re.search("America*",word):
           ind = sentence.index(word)
           print sentence[ind-1]
```

Comment: Can i edit this so i could add 2 words `America*` and `Australia*` ?

Comment: Yes you can by doing the following: `re.search(("America*|Australia*)",word)`